# Sending wchar_t through keybd_event

Tags: winapi

My question is related to the WIN32 API for a keyboard event.

```
VOID WINAPI keybd_event(
  _In_  BYTE bVk,
  _In_  BYTE bScan,
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

this method accepts a BYTE for a Key value. As long as its a char things go fine but for a wchar_t its not working, obviously because of the data type difference. Is there any method exposed for a wchar_t datatypes or any other conversion I can do to send this word on to the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send this function `char` per se, you send it a set of [Virtual Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and these are limited in their range. So trying to send it a `wchar_t` type doesn't really make any sense.

Also you'll see this note in [MSDN documentation for this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.

I should think you'd be better off using [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: `SendInput` doesn't change anything. You send all the same information. Virtual key codes and all. The main difference is that `SendInput` is more tricky to use. It's no problem using `keybd_event`.